# Program for finding longest run of zeros from a list of 100 random integers which are either 0 or 1

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have written an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970704/keyboard-interrupt-program-does-not-return-values) on Stack Overflow. To make it easier for you, I have copy-pasted the main question below.

> Write a program that generates 100 random integers that are either `0`
>   or `1`.
>
> Then find the:
>
> - longest run of zeros, the largest number of zeros in a row. For instance, the longest run of zeros in `[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]` is
>     `4`.

Here is my answer to this:

```
import random

l = []

def my_list():
    for j in range(0,100):
        x = random.randint(0,1)
        l.append(x)
    print (l)
    return l

def largest_row_of_zeros(l):

    c = 0
    max_count = 0

    for j in l:
        if j == 0:
            c += 1
        else:
            if c > max_count:
                max_count = c
            c = 0
    return max_count

l = my_list()
print(largest_row_of_zeros(l))
```

NOTE: I have changed `zero_count` to `max_count` as it sounds more sensible. It keeps track of the `max_count` (or the largest number of zeros in a row) seen so far, and if a number is not `0`, it resets the value of `c` (count) to `0` after updating the value of `max_count` with a new value.

So, I would like to know whether I could make this code shorter and more efficient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are [not allowed to change your code anymore](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Comment: What's your metric for efficiency? Shortest program, fastest execution, least memory? I mean, you're using Python and you have a tiny string; you're not going to see any user-visible efficiency wins in that scenario.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @jpmc26 - Python 3.7

Comment: For people viewing this question, please take a look at [user200345 's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219872/program-for-finding-longest-run-of-zeros-from-a-list-of-100-random-integers-whic/219942#219942) below. It provides a good solution to my question too.

Comment: Also, please take a look at [Viktor Mellgren's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219872/program-for-finding-longest-run-of-zeros-from-a-list-of-100-random-integers-whic/219976#219976), which provides a short solution to my question.

Comment: what's wrong with the various  `rle` codes?  It's 2 or 3 lines, at least in `R`; then add a line to find `max(runlength(val==0))`    Here's the base package code:  `y <- x[-1L] != x[-n]` ; 
     `i <- c(which(y | is.na(y)), n)`  ;
   `structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]), 
        class = "rle")`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - You should write this as an answer. It seems interesting.

Comment: @Justin OK, will do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Generating a random list

Instead of defining a global variable that will be modified by your generation function, you should instead define that variable inside the function and `return` it. This way, you will be able to call `my_list` a second time without having `l` being 200 items long. It will make the code easier to test.

Also note that `l` as a variable name is a poor choice as certain fonts make it hard to distinguish from `1`.

You also use the "empty list + for loop + append" pattern which can be converted to a more efficient list-comprehension:

```
def random_list(length=100):
    return [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(length)]
```

Note that, as suggested by [@jpmc26](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/25167/jpmc26) in the comments, and starting with Python 3.6, you can simplify further using [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
def random_list(length=100):
    return random.choices((0, 1), k=length)
```

## Finding the longest sequence

Your manual counting is not that bad, but usually counting a number of element can be done using either `sum` or `len` depending on the iterable at play. And finding the longest count can be delegated to `max`. So you just need to group zeroes together, count how much there is in each group and find the max of these counts.

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will happily do the grouping for you. But you won't be able to use `len` on the resulting groups, so you can add `1` for each element in said group.

Lastly, if there is no sequence of zeroes, you'll get no groups, and thus no lengths to take the maximum from, so you need to instruct `max` that the longest count is `0` in such cases:

```
def largest_row_of_zero(iterable):
    return max((sum(1 for _ in group) for value, group in itertools.groupby(iterable) if value == 0), default=0)
```

## Testing code

Instead of putting the testing code at the top-level of the file, you should take the habit of using an [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = random_list()
    print(l, largest_row_of_zero(l))
```

Comment: Looping over `random.randint` is 5 times slower (on my machine) than `random.choices(POPULATION, k=100)`, with a global list `POPULATION = [0, 1]`.

Comment: Pretty sure `numpy.random.randint(0, 1, size=100)` would make a good job here

Comment: @jpmc26 right, but `choices` is only available in latest versions and not yet an automatism

Comment: OP is [using 3.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219872/program-for-finding-longest-run-of-zeros-from-a-list-of-100-random-integers-whic?noredirect=1#comment424933_219872).

Comment: @Rightleg And then using `np.max` on a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24343375/5069029). But I fear that, for such a small problem, you spend more time importing `numpy` than you'd be able to get as speedup from it.

Answer (score 16):

**Bug** in the posted code. If you try it with the input `[1,0,1,0,0]` you will get the answer `1`. The first two lines in the `else` won't get executed if the sequence ends with the longest run of zeros. Correct code is

```
    for j in l:
        if j==0:
            c+=1
        else:
            c = 0
        if c > max_count:
            max_count = c

    return max_count
```

This can be considerably shortened and, I think, clarified:

```
    for j in l:
        c = c + 1 if j==0 else 0  # in other languages there is a ternary ?: op
        max_count = max( max_count, c) 

    return max_count
```

Two stylistic issues:

never use `l` as a variable name, it reads like `1`. Lowercase `l` is best avoided altogether unless it's part of a word in a natural language. Similar arguments against `O` and `Z` which read like `0` and `2`, but class-names starting with capital `O` or `Z` aren't so confusing.

The Pythonic form of initialization is `c, max_count = 0, 0` (one line) provided the right-hand side, in particular, needs no real thought.

Answer (score 11):

First the good: your code provides a testable function. So let's add some test code

```
def largest_row_of_zeros(l):
    '''
    >>> largest_row_of_zeros([])
    0
    >>> largest_row_of_zeros([0])
    1
    >>> largest_row_of_zeros([1])
    0
    >>> largest_row_of_zeros([0, 0])
    2
    >>> largest_row_of_zeros([0, 1])
    1
    >>> largest_row_of_zeros([1, 0])
    1
    >>> largest_row_of_zeros([1, 1])
    0
    '''

    c = 0
    max_count = 0
    for j in l:
        if j==0:
            c+=1
        else:
            if c > max_count:
                max_count = c
            c = 0
    return max_count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

which gives

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
**********************************************************************
File "main.py", line 5, in __main__.largest_row_of_zeros
Failed example:
    largest_row_of_zeros([0])
Expected:
    1
Got:
    0
**********************************************************************
File "main.py", line 9, in __main__.largest_row_of_zeros
Failed example:
    largest_row_of_zeros([0, 0])
Expected:
    2
Got:
    0
**********************************************************************
File "main.py", line 13, in __main__.largest_row_of_zeros
Failed example:
    largest_row_of_zeros([1, 0])
Expected:
    1
Got:
    0
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   3 of   7 in __main__.largest_row_of_zeros
***Test Failed*** 3 failures.
```

Here I use [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#module-doctest). Another very common module is [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#module-unittest). But you could also use simple assertions

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert largest_row_of_zeros([0]) == 1
```

Have fun with testing.

Comment: For discussions about whether or not this answer is a good answer for Code Review Stack Exchange, see [this question on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9156/31562)

Comment: @stefan - Upvoted! I tried unit-testing and I am starting to get a hang of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

To simplify the code you can:

1. You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the runs of 1s and 0s.
2. Filter if these groups to ones just containing zero.
3. Find the length of each group.
4. Return the maximum.

```py
import itertools


def largest_row_of_zeros(l):
    return max(len(list(g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(l) if k == 0)
```

---

In your code I would move the `max` aspect of the code out of the function and make the original a generator function. This allows you to use `max` to simplify the handling of the data.

```
def zero_groups(l):
    c = 0
    for j in l:
        if j == 0:
            c += 1
        else:
            yield c
            c = 0


def largest_row_of_zeros(l):
    return max(zero_groups(l))
```

Answer (score 4):

Why check all the elements? You can jump ahead k+1 elements at a time once you find k in a row. After a while you're jumping huge amounts each iteration

```
def longest_run(arr, element):
   longest = 0
   start = 0
   non_match = -1
   while start < len(arr):
       if arr[start] == element:
           current_run = 1
           while current_run <= longest and arr[start - current_run] == element:
               current_run += 1
           if current_run > longest:
               while non_match + current_run + 1 < len(arr) and arr[non_match + current_run + 1] == element:
                   current_run += 1
               longest = current_run
               non_match = non_match + current_run
           else:
               non_match = start - current_run
       else:
           non_match = start
       start = non_match + longest + 1
   return longest
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative: use `RLE` (run-length-encoding; with thanks to the comments for the correct naming), borrowed originally from a very simple data compressor of the same name.

Here's the code, albeit in the `R` language.  (For non-users,  `1L` just forces integer-class, `x[-k]` means all of vector `x` *except* index 'k'  )

Here's the base package code for the function `rle(x)` :
First line: generate logical vector of "is x[j] == x[j-1] ? "

```
  y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] ;
```

`which` returns index values when argument is TRUE, and `c` concatenates vectors (is.na just catches N/A values in case the input was skeevy)

```
 i <- c(which(y | is.na(y)), n) ;
```

finally, create a structure. First element calculates run lengths by comparing sequential index values in `i` ; second element returns the value of the input vector every time that run terminates

```
  structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]), class = "rle")
```

then add a line to find `max(lengths[values==0])`.

Comment: Is the `R` language related to Python?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! If you are not able to provide example code in the OP's requested language, it might be worth to write an informal/pseudo-code description of the algorithm if the algorithm itself is the core of your answer.

Comment: @AlexV  Done -- I hope :-)

Comment: RLE stands for Run Length Encoding, AFAIK. There is no estimation involved.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, but if the values list appears as a delimited collection, could you not just strip out the commas and split on the 1's to make an array and then reduce that? I haven't worked in python in 15 years (edit: updated to python) but this code seems to work:

```
# importing functools for reduce() 
import functools 

# initializing list 
inputString = "1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0"

#remove commas and split result into an array using 1 as the delimiter
inputString = inputString.replace(",", "")
resultArr = inputString.split("1");

# using reduce to compute maximum element from resulting array list 
longestString = (functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a if a >= b else b,resultArr)) 

#output the result
print ("The maximum element of the list is : ",end="") 
print (len(longestString))
```

Comment: Is there someway you can change the wording of your answer so that it doesn't appear to be a question. Also can you add something about why the alternate solution you provided in another language would be an improvement. Please see this help page https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: @user200345 - You could try getting some help on converting this javascript code to python. This answer seems interesting to me.

Comment: Updated my example. I was just looking to minimize the looping and lines of code that the other ideas had. This seems to work... Thanks for the comments guys.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to provide an alternate solution to the `largest_row_of_zeros` method. Easier to understand, but might not be as efficient.

```
def largest_row_of_zeros():
    asStr = reduce((lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y)), random_list())
    splitted = asStr.split("1")
    return len(max(splitted))
```

- Basically create a string `"1010010101010"`
- Split at 1s. `"","0","00","0"` ...
- Get length of longest string

Comment: Yes, this also a very good solution to my question. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Instead of using reduce, `''.join(map(str, random_list()))` is more idiomatic and understandable at a glance.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger much nicer